# How do I reconstruct class name references independent of name changes?

Tags: c#, database, logic

This is a general problem and I'm sure it's been solved.

I have several classes (components for an entity system) and I want to save some kind of reference to the classes in a file (strings or flags) as part of a save/load system. But then I want to be able to change the name of the classes in C# over time, and have it still reconstruct the correct data next time, automatically, without manually migrating the data.

Currently I am thinking there are ways to do this all automatically, assuming all the referenced classes in C# don't change at once. I could do string checks to eliminate the references which can be resolved - and then show a UI popup to resolve something like "oh, the class Renderable has been changed and it looks like the level data for Model is all pointing to this, are they the same class?". I could also lookup function names using Reflection to build a "metadata profile" of the class in question (differentiating from its name label) so the data problem is not tied to GetType().GUID or whatever (initialization order?).

If I create some simple kind of database, then the flag values would be generated in the first session and then looked up in the actual level file and reshuffled for that specific level file.. but this is where it gets complex and that's not good or helpful. What if the database file is ever lost, and there are 200+ types to resolve when loading a level file.

Maybe there is a simpler way. But in terms of information, there is only the actual class members/fields which the cpu could ever know about, without explicitly specifying and keeping an eye on it. There are no ways to raise errors with this kind of data problem, no validation checks.

One idea I had was to use mutually exclusive labels when defining the classes- force them to inherit IDummy with template parameter T, where T is from a list of further dummy interface labels so you'd choose something akin to an enum entry, which then is added to a dictionary (Type as key) to throw further errors to prevent the program from running if there's no consistent mapping between class definition and class functionality (independently of its name label). And then if I want to drop a class in the data permanently-- I just blacklist its "label".

I am doing all of this via templating tricks which relies on C# Reflection/metadata. It's possible, I know it is.

For each lightweight object (entity), all that's stored is an id and a flags value.

Comment: First off, this sounds *horrible*; why not just serialize to JSON? No type information is included

Comment: Saving data always means you have this problem. This is about old information not being linked to new information. JSON would give the same anxieties about a particular way of doing something that is not being continued in the next running of the program (because a class name label has changed, and thus everything derived from that)

This is a legitimate problem to solve (data in between sessions and program structure changes).

You always need type information if you need to differentiate what class/type is being handled!!

Hmm I guess I should just stop avoiding an explicit flag/hash.

Comment: Just because you *could* do that doesn't mean that you *should* do that. Take a step back and think about what you actually are trying to achieve. Is there a better way? Something more reasonable? Some pattern you have already heard about? You will introduce **a lot** of complexity where I doubt it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using Reflection you can dive into any assembly and pull out anything you want here's an example of extracting ClassNames.

```
   var asm = Assembly.Load("Some.Assembly.Name");
    var nameSpace = "Some.Namespace.Name";

    var classes = asm.GetTypes().Where(p =>
         p.Namespace == nameSpace &&
         p.Name.Contains("ClassNameFilter") 
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: It's a "data between sessions" problem, not a "stringize the class" problem. When the class name changes all the previous class names could be compared - but I might want to rotate class names or change them back - and this presents the issue of circular references which you haven't accounted for in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay what I am going with for now is a "dirty" solution but it's one of those things that meticulous people can live with.

I simply add an identifier which is independent from sessions/labels. I was going to use a template parameter which looks a bit cleaner.. but all I needed was to specify 1, 2, or 3 etc. as some sort of compile-time id for the classes I want to differentiate (these are indexes to look up a bitflag value to actually use)

So in the first line of the class, I now put a static int for the type id. There is a lot more to it (template base class, singletons, initialization order hacks) but it's nice and concise at least now. The only thing is I have to specify a number for each class. (which the program absolutely must know independent of class name).

The metadata idea is a poor idea because if I wanted to clone a class/component, there's no way to properly differentiate it (apart from the type name perhaps). So maybe it could work.

I didn't want to involve a "database" (a text file mapping would do - it escapes initialization order from within the compiler's naming ordering) and this is probably a good idea to avoid it, just for those corner cases (a database of 1000s of game objects for which I want to suddenly change all the class names)

It's just an inherent lack of information problem. Pretty much the only solution is to be explicit which class it is (outside of all other contexts) and throw errors for duplicate type id's.

It's not like we can't deduce, though, the program behaviour when certain things about the data changes. It should still be possible for the program to figure out what is what.. except, you have cases like one component class has exactly the same fields and members as the other, so they would both "look the same" apart from the class name, which we can't rely on when resolving what class it is. (In my scenario where it can change at any time).

Comment: Avoiding a consistent class identifier between sessions/names .. is a dogmatic OOP problem that modern industry programming STILL hasn't resolved. So this is a quite straightforward and understandable problem, at its root. In C# you can't simply define classes with a value as a template param.